# How to label std output in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a basic script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
### run these 2 commands and dump the contents to a file
run command 1 > /dir/file1
run command 2 > /dir/file2

##### run this command, echo the output and email me if $var is above a certain # and send the contents of the dump files in the email
var=$(netstat -an | wc -l)
echo $var
if [ "$var" -ge 700 ]; then
cat /dir/file1 /dir/file2 | mailx -s "System X has over $var connections. "    email recipients
fi
```

What I need to do is label the contents to distinguish between the 2 files so when I get the email I know what output came from command 1 and what came from command 2. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{ echo "From command 1:"; cat /dir/file1; echo "From command 2:"; cat /dir/file2; } | mailx -s "System X has over $var connections." email recipients
```

Comment: Don't you need some braces? `{ echo "From command 1:"; cat file1; echo "From command 2:"; cat file2; } | mailx ...` -- otherwise, the first three commands won't be included in the pipeline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right, good catch :)

Comment: The `;` after the last `cat` is actually needed if you're putting the `}` on the same line; otherwise the `}` is treated as an argument to `cat`. The spaces might be mandatory too, I'd have to check.

Comment: [Tested: Spaces are actually mandatory on both sides of the `{` and `}` characters].

Comment: `$ {echo "123"; echo "hello"; echo "abc"; echo "hello"} | grep hello
>> hello
>> hello` @CharlesDuffy I don't think the spaces and `;` are needed.

Comment: Thanks guys. Works perfectly!

Comment: @jianweichuah, which shell? I tested against bash 3.2.57(1)-release and they're certainly required there.

Comment: @jianweichuah, also, if you read the POSIX sh standard, `{` and `}` are defined as reserved words -- and something that has no spaces between it and other text isn't a standalone word.

Comment: @jianweichuah, ...to quote: "This recognition shall only occur when none of the characters is quoted and when the word is used as:

- The first word of a command

- The first word following one of the reserved words other than case, for, or in

- The third word in a case command (only in is valid in this case)

- The third word in a for command (only in and do are valid in this case)"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what do you get when you run the above command?

Comment: ...and, from the grammar specification from the POSIX sh standard: `/* These are reserved words, not operator tokens, and are
   recognized when reserved words are recognized. */`

Comment: + '{echo' 123
-bash: {echo: command not found

Comment: ...when running it with `set -x`.

Comment: Perhaps your shell might be zsh? zsh *does* actually treat `{` and `}` as operator tokens, defying the POSIX sh standard on that point (among others).

Comment: *nod* -- that's a `zsh`ism; no POSIX-compliant shell behaves that way. Might I ask that you correct your answer to be portable, or declare its portability limitations explicitly?

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. Since this question is tagged with `bash`. I'll update the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Incidentally, this is very much the reason I gave up zsh myself ~12 years ago -- realized that its deviations from the standard were making me sloppy when writing code for other shells.

Comment: Hahaha, I shall look into that ;)

Comment: I think this link will be useful for understanding bash commands grouping: `https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html`

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse `head`:

```
$ cat file1
Contents of file 1
$ cat file2
Contents of file 2
$ head -n -0 file*                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
==> file1 <==
Contents of file 1

==> file2 <==
Contents of file 2
```